# SQL SELECT query for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

```
USERS:
user_ID
username
password
email
data_registered

POSTS:
post_ID
user_ID
post_title
post_content
post_data

CATEGORY:
cat_ID
post_ID
cat_title
```

Now I used this situation:

in USERS table I have:

```
(1, 'admin, '5hj63jhn120011', 'admin@gmail.com', '15.02.2012')
```

in POSTS table:

```
(1, 1, 'Hello', 'Content goes here', '15.02.2012')
```

in CATEGORY table:

```
(1, 1, 'web developing'), 
(2, 1, 'software programming'), 
(3, 1, 'web design')
```

So I have only 1 user, 1 post, and 3 categories. How to select them in one statement? I used this statement:

```
SELECT 
  p.post_title, 
  p.post_content, 
  u.username, 
  c.cat_title 
FROM 
  posts p 
  LEFT JOIN users u 
     ON p.user_ID = u.user_ID 
  LEFT JOIN category c 
     ON c.post_ID = p.post_ID
```

but this select 3 rows with 3 different categories. I'm still learning to make this JOIN queries properly so I would appreciate any help.

And after that, for example, I will have situation to select data from COMMENTS table as well, so this is going to be complicated. Just to mention this is comment table:

```
COMMENTS:
comment_ID
user_ID
post_ID
c_username
c_email
c_content
```

It's gonna be tough to select this comments with user , post and category altogether. So one more question would be can I split this select queries and is this a good practice generaly (when developing with PHP) ?

Comment: can you provide the sample result set you need?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question bu are you sure that there should be only one post corresponding to a category?

Comment: @C.Champagne you mean one post - one category?

Comment: @BojanSavic I mean n posts - n Categories. A category should not be limited to one post I think. There should be several posts related to mysql for example. The best comparison I can make in StackOverflow is the association of tags (=categories) to questions (posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT p.post_title, 
       p.post_content, 
       u.username, 
       group_concat(c.cat_title) categories
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_ID = u.user_ID 
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.post_ID = p.post_ID
group by p.post_id
```

- if you want to see all the categories for a single post in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that:

```
SELECT 
  p.post_title, 
  p.post_content, 
  u.username, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_title + ',') cat_titles
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u 
  ON p.user_ID = u.user_ID 
LEFT JOIN category c 
  ON c.post_ID = p.post_ID
GROUP BY 
  p.post_title, 
  p.post_content, 
  u.username
```

I'm not sure in proper usage of GROUP_CONCAT, but looks like if will work

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this instead:

```
POSTS:
post_ID
user_ID
cat_ID
post_title
post_content
post_data

CATEGORY:
cat_ID
cat_title
```

As categories don't need posts to relate to but each post will need a category to relate to.

**Update:**

If many-to-many is the intention then it should be like this:

```
POSTS:
post_ID
user_ID
post_title
post_content
post_data

CATEGORY:
cat_ID
cat_title

POST_CATEGORY:
post_ID
cat_ID
```

Comment: This would be a different relationship - in the original question, a post could belong to many categories simultaneously, but in this answer a post could only ever belong to a single category.

Comment: So a post can only have one category. A better design would probably be Posts, PostCategory, Category.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'm still not good with making good database tables, I know the basic stuff, so when making few tables I put some additional complications with no need at all ;)

Comment: @Mark Well in the design it's still not correct if many-to-many was the intention as each category will be redundant with its title on each post using it, so I assumed that this is what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

without have tried it, I think the solution is:

```
SELECT p.post_title, p.post_content, u.username, c.cat_title 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.user_ID = p.user_ID
LEFT JOIN category c ON p.post_ID = c.post_ID
```

if you change the order of the ID columns, the meaning of LEFT JOIN changes. So you get three result rows....

Comment: hmm given the data the results are going to be the same.